# "The recovery attempt has failed" after HP Windows 8 Recovery Media appears to load successfully

Tags: windows-8, boot, recovery-disk

My Hp Envy Notebook hard drive failed. I ordered the identical hard drive (Samsung 760G 2.5" HDD) and installed. Ran 3 hour diagnostics on the HDD, all passed, no problems. Ran memory diagnostics, all good. I ordered up the Windows 8 recovery media and attempted to install to the new hard drive. Everything again appears to have loaded fine but when I boot I get the message

> The recovery attempt has failed

It gives me the ability to look at the log file.  The log file shows

> ```
> P2PP BurnBoot Check Failed
> ```

A little further down it shows:

> ```
> [RegistryDevicesCheck]
> Result=FAILED
> FAILED DEVICE #0:
> Description  : Unknown Device
> PNPDeviceID  : USB\VID_0000&PID_0003\5&22F3BA34&0&1
> Code         : [43]
> ```

This is the only failure in the file. I certainly appreciate any assistance in resolving this.

Comment: It looks like you have a USB connected at the time of boot and like the reason the recovery is failing.  I would also contact HP Technical Support.

Comment: Thank you for the response Ramhound!  I can assure you I do not have any USB connected.  Only thing plugged into this notebook is the power cord.  I was on the phone for approxiamtely 4 hours over the course of three days with HP Tech support.  We got no where.  This forum has helped the most.  I have changed the date on my system BIOS to 2012 and have started the recovery process once again.  I will let you know how it turns out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to a [thread in the HP support forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/restoration-failed-p2pp-burnboot-check/m-p/2562175#M133274), and several others on the HP support site, the "P2PP BurnBoot Check Failed" problem can be overcome by setting the Date in your BIOS back to 2012 until the recovery is completed.

After that's completed ensure that all applicable HP Softpaq drivers/updates are installed, and then make new recovery disks.

Specifically this one seems to be the stated cause/rememdy of the problem you're running into:  [HP Notebook PCs - Yellow Exclamation Point Next to USB-IF USB3.0 Hub in Device Manager](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03693378-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

PS: the unknown device listed in your question is your "HP Truevision HD" Webcam, and (probably) has nothing to do with the recovery failure.

Comment: Thank you Techie007! SUCCESS!!!!!  it worked and I am back up.  Thank you again